# How to recover deleted data from SQL Server?

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2012

By mistake, I deleted data from table in database. How do I recover those data from database?

Comment: same way as usual - from backup.

Comment: Kindly ask your DBA to restore it!

Comment: No BackUp. @Marcin

Comment: Database is on Azure.@jarlh

Comment: Then you need to check if Azure created any backup for you. And start doing backups.

Comment: No Backup created by Azure. @Marcin

Comment: @KaushikNandwana are you *absolutely* sure? Azure SQL takes snapshots every few minutes, just like all managed SQL services. If you mean it's just a VM on Azure, then you should have taken backups yourself

Comment: @KaushikNandwana Check this article about [automatic Azure SQL backups](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/sql-database/sql-database-automated-backups)

Comment: I am working on your suggetions @Panagiotis

Comment: Thanks all Problem solved

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this method:

https://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/3160/recover-deleted-sql-server-data-and-tables-with-the-help-of-transaction-log-and-lsns/

or if you have restore backup

Comment: I don't have .bak file. @Killer

Comment: @KaushikNandwana try the methods from the link

Comment: I tried those methods but it require .bak file of database which is not available. @KillerQueen

Comment: but here you create a backup based on logs until you deleted the data, see step 7 @KaushikNandwana

Comment: Thanks @KillerQueen Problem Solved

Comment: I am very happy :) @KaushikNandwana

Comment: Stay happy *:)*